# How to update kernel

Tags: fedora

Right after a fresh new install of Fedora 24 (I ran `dnf -y update && dnf -y upgrade`), I noticed that :

```
# rpm -qa kernel |sort -V |tail -n 1
kernel-4.6.6-300.fc24.x86_64
# uname -r
4.5.5-300.fc24.x86_64
```

So I ran `dnf install kernel-devel --best`, reboot and `uname -r` still returns me the same version.

Comment: Why didn't try a `dnf -y update && dnf -y upgrade`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did, and ran it again now. Nothing changed by that. I may update my post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your kernel is updated, but you need to reboot into the new version. Unlike other applications, for kernel updates, the **reboot** is required.

Comment: I wrote in my post that I've reboot.

Comment: Oh .. my bad. Do you see the kernel version in the grub selection during boot and in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`? Or is there still only the old one

Comment: No problem, thanks for your answer. I have a `grub2` configuration so I don't have a `/boot/grub(2)/grub.cfg` file but according to `grub-customizer` I load the correct version of the kernel.

Comment: And what about the boot menu? The `grub.cfg` should be there auto-generated regardless grub version, AFAIK.

Comment: It was a problem of boot entry. I recently installed Ubuntu in dual boot with my Fedora and it messed up my boot menu. So I was booting always on the same version instead of the most recent one as I configured it before. So you were right, just needed to reboot !